# Computing division between the number of rows of two tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables A and B. Number of rows of A is x, number of rows of B is y, and I need to compute x/y. How to do all this in one sql request.
Here is what I have tried so far :

```
select round(final,1) as final 
from (select count(*) from A/select count(*) from B )
```

But this is not working because of syntax issue I think.
Any help greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use two sub queries:

```
SELECT Round( (SELECT Count(*) FROM   a) 
            / (SELECT Count(*) FROM   b), 1) AS final
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim. This just worked fine :) But I still don't see the problem with my request yet :/

Comment: @mounaim: that's just invalid syntax ;) I don't need a `From` clause since this is just a division  of two integers. The [`From`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) must be followed by the table(s) or sub-queries and cannot be a scalar value.